# SQL Server connector

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

While working with the SQL Server 2008 in the Spark environment, I was using SQLJDBC4.jar, which happens to be a JDBC SQL Server connector.

While creating a SQLContext to query a database table from spark-shell, I got an error as below:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number
>   1435/xxx?user=xxx&password=xxx is not valid.

I asked my DB team and they said that the port number is right.
But lately, I came to know that we need to use ODBC in our environment, and not JDBC. Could we get suck error due to this connector problem? I am yet to get the ODBC downloaded and kept on linux machine.

Secondly, while launching spark-shell, I have used `--driver-class-path` to mention the jdbc full path earlier, so once I have the ODBC in place, do I need to use both of them together, or just giving the ODBC full path would work? I.e.

```
spark-shell --driver-class-path "path to JDBC" --driver-class-path "path to ODBC"
```

or just

```
spark-shell  --driver-class-path "path to ODBC"
```

Below is the JDBC url

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
     .options(Map(
          "url" -> "jdbc:sqlserver://host-IP:port/DB_name?user=user_name&password=passwd",
          "dbtable" -> "Table_name")
).load()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the JDBC connection parameters you are trying to use (connection URL, or the contents of a configuration file or method). It looks like the JDBC driver is being given `1433/xxx` as the TCP port, which is indeed not valid.

Comment: `Secondly` - well, second question should be post as a second question

Comment: The error actually suggests that your JDBC connection string is wrong, the URL parser tries to parse `1435/xxx?user=xxx&password=xxx` as a port number. Please look at the [documentation of Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url). Specifically the format of the URL should be: `jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]` yours doesn't match that format judging by the error message.

Comment: well based on suggestion here and in the link, I made some changes in my syntax, new changes as below

val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> "jdbc:sqlserver://server_IP:port;db_name;user=UID&password=pwd","dbtable" -> "tbl_name")).load().

I get below error now.

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Comment: `jdbc:sqlserver://server_IP:port;db_name` is wrong... at minimum that would need to be `jdbc:sqlserver://server_IP:port;databaseName=db_name`

Comment: @Mark, you know what...You have really come to my rescue, and became my messiah..you have helped me resolve an issue which is almost 1 week old...Namaste...!!!!

We can close this thread

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Please post and answer and then user3521180 please accept it ;)